# Using Media Player inside my app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, media-player, text-to-speech

I am running a Text To Speech code, but now my new requirement is to provide "Pause" facility. I read number of SO questions and found I have to write data into a file and have to use media player class to play the file. Below is my code.

```
public void speak(String text)
    {
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, text);

        tts.synthesizeToFile(text, map,"ttsFile.wav");


        //tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
```

Here I have 2 questions.

1. I do not want to open media player to play the file, file should be played inside the app with the media player controls (just like how you can set `videoView.setMediaController();` to `VideoView`). How can I do this? any example please?
2. Is there any "Cache" place to save the above file so it will be deleted once the app is closed?

Comment: did you try to use Surface View which will hold your Media player, for more info you can check this http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/03/play-media-on-surfaceview-using.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Create a video player in your application :

VideoPlayerActivity.java:

```
package com.camera.manual;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean mResumed = false;
    private boolean mFocused = false;
    private boolean mControlResumed = false;
    private VideoView videoView = null;
    private int stopPosition = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_TransparentVideo);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);

        setContentView(R.layout.video_view);

        videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
        MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);        
        Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.slow);        
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);        
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mResumed = false;
        if (mControlResumed) {
            if (null != videoView)
                videoView.pause();
            stopPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
            mControlResumed = false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mResumed = true;
        if (mFocused && mResumed && !mControlResumed) {
            if(null != videoView) {
                //videoView.resume();
                videoView.seekTo(stopPosition);
                videoView.start();
            }
            mControlResumed = true;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        mFocused = hasFocus;
        if (mFocused && mResumed && !mControlResumed) {
            if (null != videoView) {
                //videoView.resume();
                videoView.seekTo(stopPosition);
                videoView.start();
            }
            mControlResumed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(mContext, VideoPlayerActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: you mean convert my current class into a VideoView?

Comment: No. write a new clas like above and call it from your activity. I have edited my code to add how to call this VideoActivity class